# Where's NuGet manager console in Rider IDE?

Tags: rider

I am new to .NET platform. From time to time, I had problems with Visual Studio and I decided to use Rider. It encouraged me again (I have been using JetBrains products for 2 years). But I can not find the NuGet console (which is so called in Visual Studio).

Where is it?

Comment: NuGet console in VS is based on PowerShell and Rider doesn't support it right now. It will be implemented in future versions (probably after official release).

Answer (score 14):

It's not accessible yet. Please vote this issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-435

Comment: NuGet console in VS is based on PowerShell and Rider doesn't support it right now. It will be implemented in future versions.

Comment: I'm new to the .NET world. From what I can tell Entity Framework is a library to make interaction with data stores easier. What does this have to do with an IDE supporting a package manager's shell? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Blieque Yes. You must use package-manager console or GUI written for that.

Answer (score 9):

It is available since Rider 2018.1.
Please see JetBrains' blog post about installation: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/06/entity-framework-support-rider-2018-1/

[image]

P.S. tested on Rider 2020.2.1.

Comment: its not supported in 2020.2. I created a asp.net core solution and installed ef. Tools/Entity Framework does not exist.

Comment: @hce I'm using Rider 2020.2.1 and it's available. Did you try the right-clicking the project in the Explorer view? Please see my edited answer with an image.

Comment: @Noam_Gal I get the confusion: I'am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v3.1.7. You are using Microsoft.EntityFramework.  Rider is not supporting the core version of EntityFramework.

Comment: @hce you are right. for Core there's no such solution (yet), only this article: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/09/running-entity-framework-core-commands-rider/

Comment: If you did not found the option after right-clicking, first you must install the `EntityFramework` package and then you will see all the options for Entity Framework

Answer (score 5):

Although Rider has now added the UI for migration, unfortunately, if you use the latest dotnet feature the UI doesn't work.

For example, I created the project without Startup class file, the UI won't let me continue:

[image]

[image]

But I tried these commands which works:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

# You can type the DbContext manually now!
dotnet ef migrations add 'initial' --project src/IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj --context PersistedGrantDbContext
```

[image]

Then I execute:

```
dotnet ef database update --project src/IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj --context ConfigurationDbContext
```

Now the database updated with all the tables there:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You Can use PowerShell on Windows "Where Your DbContext is" Like this:

> dotnet ef

---

> dotnet ef migrations add [Name]

Comment: There is nothing Like NPC out of VS
So You Should find an alternative to your commands inside windows powerShell

Comment: Who gave a -1 for this answer? and why?

Comment: this is a roughly equivalent method of invoking the same/similar commands but the syntax is different and working through problems is also different

Comment: Worked for me in linux using the command "dotnet ef database update" for db updates under the project folder

Comment: This commands must be used under the project folder, not DbContext folder

Answer (score 4):

If you need to run entity framework commands such as

```
dotnet ef migrations add "initialSetup"
```

Then go to your terminal `Alt+f12` or  double-shift and type “terminal”.
Then run:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

And then (making sure you're in your project directory):

```
dotnet ef migrations add "initialSetup"
```

Answer (score 0):

They haven't implemented the Package manager console yet. So you will have to use Visual studio for that

Answer (score -4):

You can use terminal toolwindow. Or NuGet manager (GUI)...

Comment: I know where I can open terminal. But NuGet console is different(which exists in Visual Studio)